# Avoiding certain coordinates in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-canvas, artificial-intelligence

I have a 10x10 grid filled with objects in certain coordinates and I have a character that needs to get from the start to finish but I would like to avoid the certain coordinates on the route to the finish. Could someone please tell what would be the best way of approaching this in Javascript.

Also, if I was to initialise an array with the obstacles in an array how would I best code this to avoid those certain plots.

Thank you.

Comment: well, this is not javascript specific, but one popular algorithm to bypass obstacles is A* -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Comment: you can try https://github.com/bgrins/javascript-astar for example. Google a little bit and you'll find several implementations out there I guess

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for a pathfinding algorithm. The only one that comes to mind is A-Star, or "A*". The short version is that it recursively picks a random "next node" from the nodes it hasn't checked, being more likely to pick nodes that are physically closer to the goal. This is a commonly-used function that you may want to find a tutorial for (it doesn't have to be a JavaScript tutorial as long as you can reuse the concepts in JavaScript)